# DateTime "Null" = 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, .net

Como tratar um campo `DateTime` que vem como `"null"` (sei que `DateTime` não pode ser `null`) de uma base legada?

Consultando um `WebService` ele retorna um campo `DateTime` como `01/01/0001` (sem valor), no caso de uma `string` vazia ou nula existe uma forma "elegante" de se tratar`IsNullOrEmpty`

Minha questão é: Qual a melhor forma de tratar um `DateTime` "nullo", ou seja, com valor `01/01/0001`

Comment: You can try comparing it with `DateTime.MinValue.Date.ToString("d")` if think that is the elegant?

Comment: Appreciate your comment, I'll try it.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow não sei se entendi bem o que você quer. A resposta já faz o que você quer. Ou não é bem isto? Você quer que a fata seja nula? Precisa disto? Precisa só fazer algo diferente se vier esta data que você mostrou? É certeza que esta data representará sempre um dado inválido? Se der um contexto maior de como está usando, pode ter solução melhor.

Comment: Sim, a resposta faz o que eu quero visto que `DateTime.MinValue` pode ser substituído por `01/01/0001`. Eu não queria ter que compara a data com `01/01/0001` (ex: minhaData == `01/01/0001`). Eu não quero da a data seja nula, as das nulas sempre vem com `01/01/0001` do WebService.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode comparar a data com o `DateTime.MinValue` para saber se a data foi instanciada sem valor:

```
DateTime suaData = new DateTime();

if (suaData == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    //operação
}
```

E vale lembrar que o `DateTime` pode ser utilizado como *nullable*. Para isso basta adicionar um `?` após o tipo, possibilitando nesse caso ser feita a verificação de `!= null` ou utilizar o atributo `HasValue` conforme abaixo:

```
DateTime? suaData = null;

if (!suaData.HasValue)
{
    //operação
}
```